# run method 100 times and save each run in 2 D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am writing my code in Java

I have a method that returns an array which contains 24 values

I want to run this method 100 times and i want to save the result in 2 dimensional array.

I want to save each run for this method in a row

This is my code

```
int[][] multiArray = new int[101][24];
    for (int n= 0; n<multiArray.length; n++){
        for(int nn = 0; nn<multiArray[n].length;nn++){

            for(int s =0; s<100;s++){
                ActionArray =Functionss (ff, b, d, e);
                multiArray [n][nn] = ActionArray[s];
            }


            multiArray [n][nn] = ActionArray[nn];




            System.out.print(multiArray [n][nn]+"   ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: what is your problem or question

Comment: I do not know how i can do that

Comment: What is the Problem with your Code, does it throw an Exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Function xy return Object[24];

    Object[][] arr = new Object[100][24];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++{


    for(int j= 0; j <24 ; j++){
    arr[i][j] = returnof(xy)[j];
    }
```

Is this the solution u need (Pseudo code ;) )? I dont understand the question i think :)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I think you have not understand my question

Answer (score 0):

If your function returns an array of size 24 then you only need one `for` loop not 3. Also your `multiArray` should have size 100 if you only want it to run 100 times. Here is how to fill a 2d array from calling a function 100 times:

```
int[][] multiArray = new int[100][24];
for (int n= 0; n<multiArray.length; n++){
    multiArray[n]=funct(n);//whatever your function is called
}
//output- not necessary
for (int n= 0; n<multiArray.length; n++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiArray[n]));
}
```

Comment: no, you said 'I have a method that returns an array which contains 24 values' so this will put an array into each position, so a 2d array, here is an example http://ideone.com/eC4aQw

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] multiArray = new int[100][24];

for (int n= 0; n<100; n++)
{   
    multiArray[n] = Functionss (ff, b, d, e);
}

//print into sys. out.

for (int n= 0; n<100; n++)
{   
    for (int m= 0; m<24; m++)
    {   
        System.out.print (multiArray[n][m]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample program that should do what you are tryign to achieve.

```
public class ArrTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] multiArray = new int[101][24];
    int s[] = new int[24];
    for (int n= 0; n<multiArray.length; n++){
        s = new ArrTest().xyz();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            multiArray[n][i]=s[i];
        }
    }
    for (int n= 0; n<multiArray.length; n++){
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            System.out.print(multiArray[n][i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public int[] xyz(){
    int[] ret = new int[24];
    ret[2] = 3;
    return ret;
}
}
```